# Activate submit button on valid form with jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery, forms, jquery-mobile, submit, form-submit

I read a lot of documentation about jQuery Mobile, buttons and forms, but I have did not understanding everything. So, I want to deactivate a submit button until form responses are not valid.

Here is my working code...

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{
    /* $('#submit').button('enable') */ /* Console says "Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'button'" */
    $('#submit').attr("disabled", true);
    /* Do stuff */
    $('#form').live('keyup change', function()
    {
    if (isEmailValid && isTextValid)
    {
        /* $('#submit').attr("disabled", false); */ /* Button is not enable */
        $('#submit').button('enable');
    }
    });
})
...
<div class="content-primary">
    <form id="form">
    <button data-theme="a" id="submit" type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

My code is working in Chrome, Firefox and Internet Explorer, but I do not understand the logic: I turn off and turn on submit differently!

Is my solution however the right one?

Thanks for your help.

Cheers,

V.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the jQuery Mobile `button()` function to enable and disable the submit button widget:

```
$(document).delegate('[data-role="page"]', 'pageinit', function () {
    var $submit = $(this).find('#submit'),
        $text   = $(this).find('input[type="text"]');
    $text.bind('keyup', function () {
        if (this.value == '') {
            $submit.button('disable');
        } else {
            $submit.button('enable');
        }
    }).trigger('keyup');
});
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/tewV6/

Also, you want to get away from using the `document.ready` event handler when using jQuery Mobile. Instead use `pageinit` targeted at the `data-role="page"` elements like in my example above.

Comment: Oh yes!!! Very brillant. Thanks, Jasper. I will meditate (and work!) on these detailed explanations. Regards. V.

Comment: Just a very small note: the .trigger('keyup') is to trigger the initial validation, so that the submit button would be enabled immediately if all text fields has value. Brilliant trick